# How to update Feature Compatibility Version for mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am a beginner/self-taught developer and need some help. I created an app half a year ago and when I revisit it today, I noticed my MongoDB is not running as it used to.

One of the err log I got when I ran 'mongod' states:
** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document (ERROR: BadValue: Invalid value for version, found 3.6, expected '4.2' or '4.0'. Contents of featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: { _id: "featureCompatibilityVersion", version: "3.6" }. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-feature-compatibility.). If the current featureCompatibilityVersion is below 4.0, see the documentation on upgrading at http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-upgrade-fcv.

So I have 2 questions...

1. I don't recall ever updating my mongodb, so I am wondering why it worked before and not now.
2. I understand that I need to change CompatibilityVersion to 4.0, but MongoDB's documentation states you can only issue the setFeatureCompatibilityVersion against the admin database. What does the admin database mean and how do I access it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I don't recall ever updating my mongodb, so I am wondering why it worked before and not now.

Well, *someone* (or some*thing* updated it). What version did you install originally and what is the current version?

> I understand that I need to change CompatibilityVersion to 4.0, but MongoDB's documentation states you can only issue the setFeatureCompatibilityVersion against the admin database. What does the admin database mean and how do I access it?

Follow the upgrade guide you linked to. It spells out all the steps.

Comment: Thanks! I read the steps, one of the stats "Run the setFeatureCompatibilityVersion command against the admin database" I don't understand how to access the admin database, maybe I am missing something, but I couldn't find where the guide explains this.

Comment: Where are you seeing that?